# Z3 Java bindings: Why does setting produce-proofs in the SMT2 input file result in an error?

Tags: java, z3, smt

I know that proofs have to be enabled in the Context as well as in the Solver when using the Java bindings for Z3. The following program runs perfectly when the input file does **not** contain the line `(set-option :produce-proofs true)`:

```
   // Setup Context
    HashMap<String, String> cfg = new HashMap<String, String>();
    cfg.put("proof", "true");
    Context ctx = new Context(cfg);
    
   // Read input file
    BoolExpr[] program = ctx.parseSMTLIB2File(file_name, null, null, null, null);
    
   // Create Solver
    Solver s =  ctx.mkSolver();
    s.add(program);

   // Set Solver parameters
    Params p = ctx.mkParams();
    p.add("mbqi", true);
    p.add("proof", true);
    s.setParameters(p);

   // Use Solver
    Status status = s.check();
    if(status.equals(Status.UNSATISFIABLE)) {
        Expr<?> obj = s.getProof();
    }
```

However, as soon as the input file does contain the line `(set-option :produce-proofs true)`, I get the following error message when `parseSMTLIB2File` is executed:

> error setting ':produce-proofs', option value cannot be modified after
> initialization"

If my given inputs however all contain the line `(set-option :produce-proofs true)`, is there some way to ignore this line during `parseSMTLIB2File`? Or do I really have to modify the input files accordingly?

Comment: This is most likely the Java API being overly restrictive, but unfortunately there isn't much you can do. You can file a feature request at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues to see if they can relax this; but for quick turnaround you'll have to remove those lines before feeding them through the API.

Comment: I think this is not specific to the Java bindings and that all APIs would throw this error. Proof production needs to be enabled very early, so I wouldn't expect a quick fix for this.